# Spring Jpa share primary key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want my `Account` share primary key from my `User` table. So I make this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Account account;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    private String password;

    private String username;

    // bi-directional one-to-one association to User
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;
}
```

Here is my code when save new account.

```
User user= userService.get(1);
Account account = new Account();
account.username("Loi");
account.password("mypass");

contact.setAccount(account);
account.setUser(contact);

accountService.save(account);
```

Then I got this exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.amashub.tc.models.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.amashub.tc.models.User
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.save(Unknown Source)
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: You are saving the Account but the Cascade option is only defined on the User side..

Comment: I thought that it would do nothing to the user but get the reference from the user for foreign key?

Comment: Well why don't you try it and see!!

Comment: Yeah, I did, I save the user then account is saved also without error. I still dont understand the meaning of the detached object here. Detached object is the object that is disconnected from database. And it is not cascade, then why dont it ignore User?

Comment: As I have advised: User is detached when Account is saved as you have not specified Cascade on the relationship Account > User - only from User > Account. If you add Cascade then when you save an Account, the user will be saved first, followed by the Account. Obviously without this you will get an error as Account is dependent on User for its PK and so user **must** be saved first.